# Is it possible to recreate a multisig wallet with just 2 out of 3 private keys?

Tags: electrum, multi-signature

Example:

1. Created a 2 of 3 multisig wallet in Electrum
2. Send funds to the multisig wallet
3. Lost the Electrum wallet
4. Access to two of the private keys (e.g. 2 trezors)

Is it possible to recreate the wallet and move the funds through access to 2 of the private keys?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to move funds with only two private keys, however, you must still know the missing private key's public key.

The public keys are required to produce the redeem script, which is require to complete a transaction.

If you already know the redeem script (for example, it may be recorded in an old wallet file, or available on the blockchain if the same multisig address has been used to send out coins in the past), then you can spend any remaining coins with just two keys (in a 2 0f 3 multisig).